# Problems with bundle (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.0.0, and I'm just starting to learn how to use Ruby on Rails. Whenever I type the command to create a project:
    rails new blog
I get this error when the bundle tries to execute the "bundle install" command:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
  bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0) ruby

Current Bundler version:
  bundler (1.2.3)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

But with the command:
    gem list bundle
returns:
    bundler (1.3.5, 1.2.3)
And the command:
    bundle -v
returns:
    Bundler version 1.3.5

I don't know why that's happening, I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: First of all, welcome to RoR. It's really a fun thing to learn and develop awesome apps in it. What does it do when you run "gem install bundler"?

Comment: Also, in your project, what does the output says when executing the following command "bundle show rails"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the version in your Gemfile. Just keep

```
gem 'bundler'
```

Now run

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score 1):

Try check Gemfile.lock for used bundler version.

You also can try to uninstall old version:

```
gem uninstall bundler --version 1.2.3
```

Comment: I think, You should use rvm, with new ruby 2.0.0 : https://coderwall.com/p/tptocq

Comment: Thanks for help, but when I run: gem uninstall bundler --version 1.2.3. the ruby gems returns: gem "bundler" is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the version of bundler you want to use

```
bundle _1.3.5_ install
```